# Equivalent of function UploadData for PHP

Tags: c#, php, upload

I have the following script in C# to upload some XML to a Server

```
using (System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    //  Post and return Xml
    byte[] bytes = myWebClient.UploadData(url, "POST", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Xml_to_Send));
    Xml_Returned = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    bytes = null;
}
```

But i need some equivalente that do the same for PHP.

What function should i use to simule somthing like that ?

Comment: Where are you getting the XML from? Via a web form? Or are you generating it yourself?

Comment: the XML is and String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library to upload files that way. Check this guide:

http://blogs.digitss.com/php/curl-php/posting-or-uploading-files-using-curl-with-php/